# 9x9 Sudoku Puzzle

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

This is a standard 9x9 sudoku puzzle from a book I hope to publish:
[image: Standard Sudoku puzzle]

Comment: If this is a simple sudoku I don't see the point of posting it here.  This site is more about creating new types of puzzles, with original or alternate rules.

Comment: @FlorianF Really? I've been under the impression that all puzzles and questions about puzzles would be welcome here.

Comment: You are right, it is not forbidden, but I believe it is not in the spirit of PSE to post a standard sudoku, of which you can find plenty elsewhere.  https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7107/are-just-plain-sudokus-allowed

Comment: Sorry Stevo, I am a bit slow on the uptake with the way Puzzling Stack Exchange works. I have only just noticed and approved your suggested edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we solve...

> A9, as we can be completely sure of its value. We proceed like this, finding the squares that are available and we can be sure of their value.

After multiple repetition, we get the final result:

> [image: solved puzzle]

Comment: Thank you for solving my puzzle. My book will have an acknowledgements page at the start and I will say that you tested puzzle 13 for me.  I will call you smlee from Puzzling Stack Exchange. If you would like me to use your real name instead, let me know and we can work out how you can get a private message to me.

Comment: @InternationalDBA 'smlee for Puzzling Stack Exchange' is fine. May I ask what the book is about?

Comment: Yes. It is just a book of 400 tough sudoku puzzles. If there is any demand for it, I now have all the software I need to produce books of diabolical and extreme puzzles. However, as I'm sure you will understand, getting people to look at sudoku puzzles is a bit like wading through treacle so those books may never see the light of day.

Comment: I see. Thanks @InternationalDBA.

Answer (score 0):

I logged in back after years And saw sudoku. I loved spending 10 minutes here. :)
[image]

Thanks